# Regular expression is required to add a custom validation method in jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I want to do validation of a password field on a login form. The requirement for the password is that the **password should be combination of alphabet and numbers**.  I write a new validation function to fulfil above requirement and added it to jQuery using `validator.addmethod()`. The function code is as follows

```
$.validator.addMethod('alphanum', function (value) {
    return /^[a-zA-Z 0-9]+$/.test(value);
}, 'Password should be Alphanumeric.');
```

Problem is this function is not working properly i.e. it accepts alphabetic password (like
**abcdeSD**) and numerical password (like **4255345**) and dot give error message for such inputs.

1. so is there anything wrong in my code?
2. is the written regular expression is wrong and if yes then what will be the correct reg expression?

Comment: Accept some answers! You've got a 0% rate.

Comment: Hi Gumbo! 
My aim to validate password is to avoid sql injection because of that I am validating password.

Comment: If SQL injection is your only reason for validating then this is not the right way to do it. It looks like you're trying to encourage people to increase their password strength (but you allow passwords of length 1?).

Comment: Thanks Mark! for your comment but I am not allowing passwords of length 1. I have made the validation for password length using maxlength and minlength.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use negative lookaheads to disallow what you don't want:

```
^(?![a-zA-Z]+$)(?![0-9]+$)[a-zA-Z 0-9]+$
```

Comment: Thank You Mark!
The regular expression you have given is working perfect man.
thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Password must contain *only* alphabets *and* digits

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/
```

It must contain alphabet(s)

```
/[a-zA-Z]+/
```

It must contain digit(s)

```
/[0-9]+/
```

And'ing these

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/.test(value) && /[a-zA-Z]+/.test(value) && /[0-9]+/.test(value)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this expression for password for javascript:

```
/((?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#$%_!]).{8,8})/
```

You can add the any special characters in the expression.

Manually add the characters for in `[@#$%_!]` inside.